# How to sort a Set<String> alphabetically in Dart/Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, set

I know there is the `List<string>`, but I need to use a `Set<string>`. Is there a way to to sort it alphabetically?

```
Set reasons = {
  'Peter',
  'John',
  'James',
  'Luke',
}
```

Comment: The type of set is not specified. Docs mention the Set to be **unordered**. So what is the point of sorting it? I don't understand.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use a [`SplayTreeSet`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.1/dart-collection/SplayTreeSet-class.html) instead:

```dart
import 'dart:collection';

...

final sortedSet = SplayTreeSet.from(
  {'Peter', 'John', 'James', 'Luke'},
  // Comparison function not necessary here, but shown for demonstrative purposes 
  (a, b) => a.compareTo(b), 
);
print(sortedSet);

// Prints: {James, John, Luke, Peter}
```

As jamesdlin points out, the comparison function is not necessary if the type implements `Comparable`.

Comment: Note that although the example here explicitly passes a comparison callback (which I'm assuming is for demonstrative purposes), the callback isn't necessary if the elements are already `Comparable` (which `String`s are).

Answer (score 6):

You can convert a set to a list and call the sort method. Then you can convert that list to a set again. You can also create a handy extension method on Set that does the same thing.

```dart
Set reasons = {
  'Peter',
  'John',
  'James',
  'Luke',
};
final reasonsList = reasons.toList();
reasonsList.sort();
print(reasonsList.toSet());
```